# emacs crashes at least 10 times a day

Tags: debugging, crash

9 out of 10 times it happens when invoking magit with `C-x g`.

I noticed (sometimes) pressing 'g' for refresh inside a dired buffer crashes too.

There's no error shown. My `-nw` emacsclient just lands in a corrupted shell prompt, where I have to type `reset` to even start seeing characters I type in to the shell.

```
administrator@Administrators-MacBook-Pro-2$ emacs --version
emacsclient -a  -s example -nw --version
emacsclient 27.1
administrator@Administrators-MacBook-Pro-2$ brew upgrade emacs
Warning: emacs 27.1 already installed
administrator@Administrators-MacBook-Pro-2$ uname -a
Darwin Administrators-MacBook-Pro-2.local 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Sun Jul  5 00:43:10 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~9/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
administrator@Administrators-MacBook-Pro-2$
```

What I tried:

```
M-:
(byte-recompile-directory package-user-dir nil 'force)
```

**note** im not shown a backtrace because pretty much i get ejected to the shell.

Comment: Are you using Magit together with the `libgit`/`magit-libgit` packages by any chance?  If so, it might be a bug in those dynamic modules.  Otherwise, please report the problem upstream with `M-x report-emacs-bug` and as many details as you can gather, especially the backtrace, etc.  See [`BUGS`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/BUGS), [`(info "(emacs) Lossage")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lossage.html) and its subnodes, and [`etc/DEBUG`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/DEBUG).

Comment: Re: not being shown a backtrace - follow the instructions linked in my previous comment for running Emacs under `gdb` or `lldb`.

Comment: after doing a M-x gdb
after my normal emacs -nw start,
I got a 'apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, gdb' so I guess u have to grab gdb from homebrew

Comment: that file is so lengthy https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/DEBUG

Comment: Re: `etc/DEBUG` being lengthy - if you view it in its intended `outline-mode` within Emacs, you can expand the specific outline headings you're interested in, like viewing a table of contents.

Answer (score -1):

That gdb ninja stuff, I never got around to doing.

In hindsight, I feel I shouldn't have been running emacs 27 when brew makes 28 available.

I did a

```
brew install emacs --HEAD
```

and its been running a day without crashing.

sidenote: use-package broke after the re-install. i had to Meta-: eval some lisp to get it back up.

sidenote: the brew install broke my Postgres, and my `psql -l` shows zero of my  local work databases. Instead of trying to rectify this, I'm simply going to re-download databases from a live site.